# How to unconditionally re-run a python program based on button click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

At the end of my program execution, I want a popup message to appear that has a button which can re-run a program. Obviously, I will have setup a function that the button calls when it is clicked, as such

```
def restart():
    **python command that makes the whole program restart**
```

Then I would attach this function to the following button:

```
B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text='Restart program', width=17, command=lambda: restart())
```

Is there such a command?

Quick note:I found an answer but it doesn't work, here it is:

```
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

Comment: Wrap the 'starting method' (`main` or similar) in another method that either calls it again or exits, depending on the state of a variable set by the restart popup.

Comment: @match Can you please elaborate because I didn't anything you just said :)

Comment: Can you please explain the problem you want to solve by restarting in details?

Comment: I think what @match is saying is to put all of your code in a function: `def main(): # all code goes here`. Then instead of `restart()`, the button can just call `main()`.

Comment: Added an answer to elaborate

Comment: Also as an aside, instead of `lambda: restart()` you can just use `restart` without parentheses to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the `subprocess` module to re-execute the program which was designed to replace the older `os.exec...()` group of functions.

Here's a runnable (i.e. complete) example of how to use it to restart the script, which was tested on Windows with Python 3.6.4:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import traceback

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill="none", expand=True)  # Center the button.
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.restart_btn = tk.Button(self, text='Restart', command=self.restart)
        self.restart_btn.grid()

    def restart(self):
        command = '"{}" "{}" "{}"'.format(
            sys.executable,             # Python interpreter
            __file__,                   # argv[0] - this file
            os.path.basename(__file__), # argv[1] - this file without path
        )
        try:
            subprocess.Popen(command)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            sys.exit('fatal error occurred rerunning script')
        else:
            self.quit()


app = Application()
app.master.title('Restartable application')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially an over-simple approach, but say your existing program looks something like:

```
def my_app():
    # Code goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

Instead wrap it like this:

```
def my_app():
    print("App is running!")
    # Your app code goes here
    print("App is exiting!")
    # On exit popup a prompt where selecting 'restart' sets restart_on_exit to True
    # Replace input() with a popup as required
    if input("Type y <return> to restart the app! ").lower() == "y":
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    restart_on_exit = True
    while restart_on_exit:
        restart_on_exit = my_app()
```

That way the code will loop, running `my_app` over and over again, if the popup sets `restart_on_exit` to `True` before the loop repeats.

Comment: I'm envisaging that `my_app` is a long running interactive GUI, which will block on the popup to ask about restarting, so a sleep seems unnecessary, but for a short-lived non-interactive method, sure.

Comment: I think this is a better approach than restarting entire script, but the code snippets you use could've been better if they were [mcve]s.